# Laravel eloquent query convert created_at datetime to date

Tags: laravel

i am querying the database the get my tracker results:

```
$trackers = TrackerResult::all()
    ->where('tracker_id', $id)
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30));

return $trackers;
```

But this returns me "created_at" field as datetime as its by default. Is there are way to get just the date instead? ('Y-m-d') format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare date only try `->whereDate()`:

```
TrackerResult::all()
        ->where('tracker_id', $id)
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30));
```

You could also manually format it using `->format()`:

```
TrackerResult::all()
        ->where('tracker_id', $id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
$trackers = TrackerResult::all()
    ->where('tracker_id', $id)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
->select('column1',column2',DB::raw('Date(created_at) as formattedCreateAt'))
->get();


return $trackers;
```